Get blur effect inside a backdrop using ass format
I have created an backdrop with rounded corners using drawing command. Example of dialog for backdrop.
Dialogue: 0,00:00:38.60,00:00:42.10,Default,,0,0,0,,{\p1\1a&HD8&\c&HE27FA4&\pos(341.07421875,517.5)\an4}  {\p1}m 15 0 b 1202.8515625 .... {\p0}

Now I want to make the backdrop blur. (Text backdrop by ass formatting)
I have tried to use \blur or \be, but they are for other purpose. Below is reference from the doc
Enable or disable a subtle softening-effect for the edges of the text

Is there any other way to achieve the blurred backdrop. I am ready even to mix ffmpeg commands like boxblur and ass file. I mean separately paint the backdrops and then apply ass subtitles file. Here is an experiment to explain the idea.
[0:v]split=3[base][blur1_in][blur2_in];

[blur1_in]crop=w=100:h=100:x=20:y=40[region1];
[region1]boxblur=luma_radius=10:luma_power=1[blurred_region1];
[base][blurred_region1]overlay=x=20:y=40:enable='between(t,0,5)'[tmp1];

[blur2_in]crop=w=30:h=30:x=20:y=40[region2];
[region2]boxblur=luma_radius=5:luma_power=1[blurred_region2];
[tmp1][blurred_region2]overlay=x=20:y=40:enable='between(t,5,10)'[tmp2];

[tmp2]ass=../logs/ass.ass:fontsdir=../fonts/Audiowide-Regular.ttf[final_video]

The problem in this case is that the corners are not rounded. Could anyone explain to me what is the easiest way to get backdrop with rounded corners an blurred inside
